# How to add authentication persistence to Vue.js AWS-amplify app

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, vue-router, aws-amplify

I am attempting to build an AWS-Amplify authentication page for a Vue.js app. So far, I have been successful in implementing a login/logout module using the `aws-amplify` and `aws-amplify-vue` plugins. I have also implemented a route guard in router.js that prevents the unauthorized access. I am however, running into an issue where, after logging in, clicking the back arrow in the browser returns to the login menu even though I am still logged into the app. In previous apps that I've built using Firebase, I would normally add `.onAuthStatechanged()` method to the main.js (the entry point file) to handle authentication persistence, like so:

```
let app = ''

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if (!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
})
```

Is there a method similar to this in AWS Amplify or the `aws-amplify-vue` plugin? If not, are there any recommendations on how to implement auth persistence? Is there perhaps a way to configure the route guard to handle this? See my route guard below:

```
router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    let user;
    Vue.prototype.$Amplify.Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(data => {
      if (data && data.signInUserSession) {
        user = data;
      }
      next()
    }).catch((e) => {
      next({
        path: '/'
      });
    });
  }
  next()
})
```

Comment: You assign `user = data` but don't use `user`. I've seen this code before, but I still don't understand why this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [awsamplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/vue#manage-auth-state-and-conditional-app-rendering) documentation you can use a function called onAuthUIStateChanged which can be called upon creation to check the AuthState if it is "signedIn" then simply push the router to the home view. This would be the function in the Login.Vue view.

```
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components`;

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  created() {
    onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
      if (nextAuthState === AuthStatus.SignedIn) {
          console.log('user successfully signed in!');
          this.$router.push('/profile');
        }
      if (!authData) { console.log('user is not signed in');
        }
     });
   }
```